# CSS media min-width not applying all styles

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have the following CSS styles:

```
@media (min-width: 1280px)
{
    .window-padding {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-right: 30px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 769px)

{
    .window-padding {
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
}

.window-padding {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

However, when I open in browser (width > 1280px), only padding-top and padding-bottom from min-width:1280px is applied. padding-left and padding-right is from style that doesn't have a @media condition.
Here is the what it applies:

[image]

**EDIT**:
I reordered CSS to have the lowest size first fixed the issue. 
Also, I have duplicate padding styles by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First u go for default style ( after that increase the screen rez )
that means default > 768 > 1280 ( this apply for min-width )
if u choose to use max-width ( u go Default > 1280 > 768 )

for min width

```
.class {
  your style
}
@media screen (min-width: 768) {
  override default
}
@media screen (min-width: 1280) {
  override 768
} and so on
```

for max-width

```
.class {
  your style
}
@media screen (max-width: 1280) {
  override default
}
@media screen (min-width: 768) {
  override 1280
} and so on
```

Answer (score 3):

Always call `@media` styles after your `main` css file(s), this may help you to override styles.

```
.window-padding {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
@media (min-width: 1280px)
{
    .window-padding {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-right: 30px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1279px)
{
    .window-padding {
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: @madu updated my ans, set limit to `@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1279px)`

Answer (score 2):

reorder your css & Add `Max-width`

```
 .window-padding {
        padding-right: 50px;
        padding-left: 50px;
    }


    @media (min-width: 1280px) {
        .window-padding {
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            padding-left: 30px;
            padding-right: 30px;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1279px)  {
        .window-padding {
            padding-right: 20px;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Laiji. I reordered but now it applies padding-left and padding-right from min-width: 769px.

Comment: did u try default / 769 than 1280 ? in that order ?

Answer (score 0):

> Could anybody please advise why this is happening?

More important CSS styles should come at more lower level